# Получение курсора во время события scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю кастомный курсор через div и возникла проблема в том, что я не могу получить координаты реального курсора при скроле, от чего мой курсор при скроле остается на месте, что выглядит некрасиво.

`e.pageX; e.pageY;` Работают только при клике/движении мышью.

Есть ли возможность получить эти значения при скроле?

Comment: зачем через div? вот же гайд https://css-tricks.com/using-css-cursors/

Comment: Пока накостылял так: Добавил в событие mousemove запоминание положения скрола, а в событии scroll координату Y обрабатываю как: старая_координата - старое_положение_скрола + новое_положение_скрола (которое только что измерил)

Comment: в событиях mousemove есть свойства `e.movementX` и `e.movementY`, которые отвечают за относительное смещение (ими пользоваться легче, так как не нужны старые координаты `div.offsetLeft+=e.movementX`и`div.offsetTop+=e.movementY`). divу можно прописать CSS `position: fixed` и тогда он не будет зависеть от скрола

Comment: Хз, e.movementX не сработал, но зато нашел ```e.clientY```, которые как ```e.pageY``` только вне зависимости от скрола. И юзанул pasition: fixed;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поменял `e.pageX; e.pageY;` на `e.clientX; e.clientY;`, которые не зависят от скрола.

И в css установил `position:fixed` для моего div-курсора.

Comment: это ответ?.....

Comment: ____ Мне хватило)

Comment: я поинтересовался, является ли это ответом....плюсанул